# Proper Term for SQL Superquery Summary Wrapper Structure

Tags: sql, oracle

What is the best way to refer to the wrapping of a full query with a

```
SELECT count (*) FROM (
       COMPLETE QUERY
)
```

query?

Since 'wrapper queries' like this typically are so much less substantial than the query inside, it seems a little silly to refer to the internal query as a subquery. 
I have never heard of or seen reference to a superquery, and though linguistically this seems the best solution, according to Google I appear to be alone on this.

1) What is the proper term for this 'superquery' or aggregating 'wrapper' structure?

2) Is there a way to perform these easily in the Query Builder GUI of Oracle SQL Developer (or Toad)? [I know how extremely simple adding the 'wrapper' to the original query is, but I do want to help those afraid of (or morally opposed to?) writing SQL code to be able to easily get the results they seek.]

Comment: It's called a "derived table".

Comment: Aha! With the keywords I can reference the documentation:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually call the query being wrapped an "inline view", and I'm slightly relieved to see [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries007.htm) uses that phrase too:

> A subquery in the FROM clause of a SELECT statement is also called an **inline view**.

So the 'superquery' is just a query against an inline view. It's sometimes also referred to as an "outer query".

Comment: The SQL standard calls this a "derived table", the term "inline view" is not specified by the SQL standard

Comment: @ Alex Poole: Thank you for the documentation reference, too. Great to learn all about the relatives too.